# Running CircleCI 2.0 workflows on tags, REGEX

Tags: regex, continuous-integration, circleci

I have a circleci integrated github repository, I am running CircleCI 2.0
I want one workflow, test, to run on all branches and tags, so long as the tag does not match the pattern v*.*.* with an optional ending. And anything matching the pattern v*.*.* should be run through the deploy workflow. For example these tags should, v0.0.1 be run through deploy, v0.0.1beta should be run through deploy, v0.1beta or betav0.1.1 should be run through test instead. What would the appropriate regex to match this be, and if you are familiar with circleci 2.0, what changes do I need to make to this section of the configuration file in order for this to work.

`workflows:
  version: 2
  test:
    jobs:
      - build:
          filters:
            tags:
              ignore:
                - /^v[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9].+/
            branches:
              only:
                - /.*/
      - lint:
          requires:
            - build
  deploy:
    jobs:
      - build
          filters:
            tags:
              only:
                - /^v[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9].+/
            branches:
              ignore:
                - /.*/
      - lint:
          requires:
            - build
      - deploy:
          requires:
            - lint`

Comment: @wp78de Just varying regex statements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
^v\d\.\d\.\d\w{0,5}$
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will mark this as correct as it seems to be valid regex for this. It turns out that the error is something strange on CircleCI's end, it wasn't matching anything to the regex that I had input. Thanks for your help